# Formatting INSERT SQL statements to align column name and values

Tags: sql, formatting

I would like to know if there is any tool(preferably online) which can format SQL statements so that the column names and values for each column is aligned

e.g. I would like to format following INSERT statement

`INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country) VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway')`;

to look like this

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName,    City,    Country)
                VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway');
```

so that I can easily see the value for each column. In my case I have a table with around 50 columns and it's difficult to see the values at a glance for each column. Tried googling about it but no success.

Thank You

Comment: Here you go! Copy the logic into your language. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573661/how-where-to-format-insert-statement-by-aligning-columns-with-values/74609752#74609752